# Dell E6410 laptop with Dell E1909 external monitor resolution stuck at 640x480

Tags: multiple-monitors, displayport, resolution, dell-latitude

I have a new Windows 7 (32-bit) Dell Latitude E6410 laptop, and a new Dell E1909WDD Flat Panel Monitor.

The only way to connect to the monitor is via an integrated DisplayPort cable. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort

There is no VGA or other alternative. The monitor supports DisplayPort only.

The problem is that the monitor will not allow any other resolution than 640x480.

In Windows 7 Control Panel | Display | Screen Resolution, I can detect the E1909WDD as display #2, but the resolution drop-down is stuck at 640 x 480 - the resolution drop-down control is disabled.

In Control Panel | Devices and Printers, the monitor is showing as "Generic Non-PnP Monitor". In the monitor's hardware properties | Driver Details it shows:

> Driver Provider: Microsoft
>
> Driver Date: 21/06/2006
>
> Driver Version: 6.1.7600.16385

The CD which came in the box contains driver files as follows.

> D:\driver\Win7
>
> Volume in drive D is Dell E1909WDD 
>   Volume Serial Number is 2C1F-9E5E
>
> Directory of D:\driver\Win7
>
> 26/08/2009  07:37              .
>   26/08/2009  07:37              ..
>   19/05/2009  06:06             2,964
>   E1909WDD.icm 19/05/2009  06:05
>   1,558 E1909WDD.inf 27/05/2009  18:32
>   7,381 e1909wdd.cat
>                  3 File(s)         11,903 bytes
>                  2 Dir(s)               0 bytes free

When I try to update the drivers for the monitor, pointing at D:\driver\Win7, Windows 7 tells me the following:

```
The best driver for your device is already installed

Windows has determined the driver software for your device is up to date.
```

I'm grateful for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

[Extended display identification data (EDID)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data) of monitor is messed up probably .

Try checking it with this

> http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dump_edid.html.

Comment: DumpEDID v1.01

Copyright (c) 2006 Nir Sofer

Web site: http://www.nirsoft.net



*****************************************************************

Registry Key             : DISPLAY\DELD020\4&ce3f802&0&UID51249920

Monitor Name             : DELL E1909WDD

(snip)

Supported Display Modes  :

     640 X  480  60 Hz

Comment: In other words, just 640 x 480 supported according to DumpEDID

Comment: @mcaleaa Oh wow, looks like this might actually be the problem then.  There are ways of fixing this but honestly you're better off doing an RMA on the monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;286906&x=9&y=13

For Windows 7 though:

1. Go to Control Panel;
2. All Control Panel Items;
3. Display;
4. Screen Resolution;
5. Detect your monitor;
6. Then go to Advanced Settings;
7. Then it's the same (under the Adapter tab, click "List all modes", choose "640X480, true color (32 bit), XX hertz").

You might have to first slide the resolution to higher ones first before sliding it back to 640X480 before you can apply, and choose "duplicate display/monitor" (either one, I forgot) instead of "extend display".

Answer (score 0):

Silly question - you are using the DisplayPort port on the laptop rather than an adapter, right?

Also, you did update the VIDEO drivers, right?  (Monitor drivers are usually only color profiles and can actually cause more harm than good - try removing that as well.)

Comment: Yes, it's the DisplayPort port on my laptop. I'm not using an adapter.

Comment: Here's my silly question: In Windows 7 where can I update *video* drivers? I've tried updating Device Manager | Display Adapters | Intel(R) HD Graphics both using Windows Update and the CD provided by Dell. In both cases I get the response "The best driver for your device is already installed".

Comment: You should visit the manufacturer's website and manually download the newest driver.